# Is my fast invalidated if I accidently swallow when spitting out toothpaste after brushing my teeth?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, doubts

I went to spit out water when to get all the toothpaste out of my mouth when I felt cold water in my throat or near it I trying to cough it out but I couldn’t and then I swallowed.

**Does this break my fast?**

Answer (score 1):

No you can still fast because you swallowed it by accident.

> Khuzaymah (1999) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever breaks his fast in Ramadaan by mistake does not have to make up that day or offer expiation.” Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Khuzaymah.